In the logging, the Level of log is less than the Level set by the handler, but the log is recorded
The log level set by the handler is logging.ERROR, but the warning log is printed.
import logging

# root logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.root.addFilter(logging.Filter("root"))
for handler in logging.root.handlers:
    handler.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

# my logger
logger = logging.getLogger("myLog")
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
handler1.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler1)

# my logger log
logger.debug("logger debug")
logger.info("logger info")
logger.warning("logger warning")  # why
logger.error("logger error")
logger.critical("logger critical")

Output:
WARNING:myLog:warning
error
ERROR:myLog:error
critical
CRITICAL:myLog:critical

I expect to only print logs with ERROR and above.

logging.basicConfig creates a handler for the root logger. Logger objects have an attribute propagate that defaults to True, which means that logs are propagated to handlers of ancestor loggers (like the root logger). Since the logging level of your logger is set to logging.WARNING, logger.warning actually creates a log report that is passed to two handlers:

The StreamHandler that you created, doesn't print the log message as its level is logging.ERROR
The handler of the root logger that was created automatically by logging.basicConfig. Its level was set to logging.INFO in the loop that you wrote. Note that this handler uses a different formatter.

This explains why you get 5 log messages:
WARNING:myLog:warning    # printed by the handler of the root logger
error                    # printed by your handler
ERROR:myLog:error        # printed by the handler of the root logger
critical                 # printed by your handler
CRITICAL:myLog:critical  # printed by the handler of the root logger


The sentence "logger.warning actually creates a log report that is passed to two handlers" means that the level (logging.ERROR) of StreamHandler  will not prevent it(logging.warning()) from spreading to the root logger，correctly?

yes, the handlers are independent of each other. Each handler decides on its own if it writes the log record that is sent to it.
